# Inefficient numpy code

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

In Python I'm using the numpy package to do some math with matrices. In the code below I'm trying to calculate a new matrix from my orignal. `xFactors` and `yFactors` are both `3x3` matrices.

```
size = self.matrix.shape

for x in range(1, size[0] - 1):
    for y in range(1, size[1] - 1):
        subMatrix = self.matrix[x-1:x+2, y-1:y+2]

        newX = (xFactors * subMatrix).sum()
        newY = (yFactors * subMatrix).sum()

        self.newMatrix[x-1][y-1] = newX + newY
```

My problem is that this code is very inefficient. I tested te code with a `500x500` matrix and it takes up to two seconds. Do you have any ideas how I can optimize this code?

Comment: Looks like you could use 2D convolution there with xFactors and yFactors as kernels separately on `matrix` as input data. So, look into Scipy's convolve2d.

Comment: @Divakar only If `xFactors` and `self.matrix` are both `numpy.array` and not `numpy.matrix` (in other words if OP is using element-wise multiplication and not matrix multiplication in calculating `newX` and `newY`

Comment: Yes both are of the type `numpy.array`. @Divakar can you explain this a bit more? Do you mean the scipy method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `xFactors` and `self.matrix` are both `numpy.array` and not `numpy.matrix` (in other words if you are using element-wise multiplication and not matrix multiplication in calculating newX and newY), then this should do the same thing a lot faster:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

self.newMatrix = convolve2d(self.matrix, xFactors + yFactors, mode='valid')
```

In the original code, it was not clearly stated that xFactors and yFactors were square. If they weren't one would need to make them square by repeating them as needed if the above addition doesn't broadcast correctly.

Comment: For this to work, I think `xFactors` and `yFactors` need to be square, whereas in the original code, they would broadcast as needed. So really, this should start with a `xFactors, yFactors = np.broadcast_arrays(xFactors, yFactors)` to be equivalent

Comment: @Eric you are right, but the OP didn't mention that. For completeness, I'll add a note about that to my answer.

Comment: Actually, better yet - add before convolving, since convolution distributes over addition - should be a fair bit faster, and does the broadcasting for free

Comment: @Eric Awesome - I should have seen that.

Comment: _if the above addition doesn't broadcast correctly_ - there is no case when this happens and the origin code still works. The only condition for this working is that at least one of the factors is not a scalar, else the convolution decays to a multiplication

Comment: If `xFactors` and `yFactors` are both (3,1) or both (1,3) the convolution will not work the same way as in the original code and the addition will not broadcast to (3,3).

Comment: If I change `self.newMatrix[x-1][y-1] = abs(newX) + abs(newY)` in the code above to `self.newMatrix[x-1][y-1] = abs(newX) + abs(newY)` can I use `convolve2d` with `abs(xFactors + yFactors)` as argument or how should I change the code?

Comment: You would need to call `convolve2d` twice and call `abs` on both the results.

Comment: You mean: `m1 = abs(convolve2d(matrix,...))` and `res = abs(convolve2d(m1,...))`?

Comment: No, `self.newMatrix = abs(convolve2d(self.matrix, xFactors, mode='valid')) + abs(convolve2d(self.matrix, yFactors, mode='valid'))`.